# How to create one handler for several urls in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've got some troubles when start working with Next.js

Here is the deal. I have multiple filters, depends on them I make up URL. All of this URL's for one page.
It can be like:

- /
- /one
- /one/two
- /one/two/three

This nested is required. How can I create one handler for catch any of these URL's?

I use Express like this, but it doesn't help.

```
server.get('/*', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      app.render(req, res, '/')
    } catch (e) {
      next(e)
    }
  })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use Dynamic routing like that :

```
pages/[one]/[two]/[three].js
```

cf:
Multiple dynamic route segments work the same way.

For example, `pages/post/[pid]/[comment].js` would match `/post/1/a-comment`. Its query object would be: `{ pid: '1', comment: 'a-comment' }`.

https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing

Hope it's help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used dynamic routes, but I have only one page for these few url's. Is it possible handle all urls by one page?

Answer (score 1):

**New feature introduced in Next.js 9.5**

Solution: [Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

See also: Redirects & Headers:

Announcing comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/9081#discussioncomment-48301

Besides that I am aware of some wildcard matching that nests paths deep in the default routing, but I feel Rewrites is a better solution in most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

use npm next-routes in order to use path patterns (regex) to bind multiple urls to a page